# NSwag include null values for properties

Tags: c#, openapi, nswag

In an OpenAPI document I have specified for a property that the value may also be null.

Here is an example of a property:

```
"PersonBirthdate": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "format": "date"
                        
                    }
```

NSwag generates me this code from it:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("PersonBirthdate", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter))]
```

But I need the following result:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("PersonBirthdate", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter))]
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a way that null values can be included.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve the problem myself.
NSwag provides a partial method UpdateJsonSerializerSettings.
I used this method as follows:

```
 partial void UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        settings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
        
    }

 internal class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
 {
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        switch(property.PropertyName)
        {
            //Account                
            case "PersonBirthdate":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;
            case "EmailOptInDate__pc":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;
            case "EmailDoubleOptInDate__pc":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;
        
            //Contact
            case "Birthdate":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;
            case "EmailOptInDate__c":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;
            case "EmailDoubleOptInDate__c":
                property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                property.Required = Required.Default;
                break;

        }

        return property;
    }
}
```